# Azure DateTimes in a legacy application

Tags: c#, datetime, utc

I am porting an application to ASP.NET MVC in Azure. The application was written with no mind to time zones or daylight savings, it basically assumes the app will only ever be used in-house in Texas. Thus, I have tons of data assuming DateTime is in central standard time, and the code is littered with DateTime.Now and GETDATE().

So, in moving to Azure, I have discovered that everything uses UTC, and there is no way to set the time zone of the cloud service or SQL database. This is unfortunate, because it's thousands of lines of code I've inherited, and I'm really restricted in the changes I can make because of government/legal reasons.

What is the best way to deal with this? Here's my thoughts so far:

- When I display data to the user, I can just use DateTime.ToString() since it's already in CST.
- When I get data from the user, I can just parse it to DateTime as they entered it, since they assumed CST.
- When comparing things to DateTime.Now, I need to be aware that I'm dealing with UTC DateTimes. What's the best way to do this? I'm thinking of adding my own property called LocalizedDateTime, which uses TimeZone.ToLocalTime to convert from DateTime.UtcNow to my time zone, and comparing db values to that. Is this the best way to go about it, or is this a bad idea?
- When querying things, I need to find a replacement for GETDATE() where I can specify the time zome. What's the best way to go about this?

Note that I keep talking about CST, but in reality we're moving this to the cloud because we hope to start targeting areas out of state. So it would need to be abstracted where I can specify the time zone.

I realize this is kind of an abstract question and I apologize for that, but I'm really frustrated right now since this was kind of unexpectedly sprung on us. Any help/ideas?

Comment: I'm very biased, but I'd suggest looking at Noda Time (http://nodatime.org) as it'll help you keep things straight in your mind, rather than the single `DateTime` type which means different things... Also, I'd recommend storing UTC in your database in general, although it depends on your exact situation.